# crntab and htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, cron

I need to call a php script via cron. The cron entry will use wget. When I attempt to call the script from a command line, I get "Authorization Required", which is obviously coming from my htaccess file.

Does anyone know how I can override the htaccess file for a single directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Satisfy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#satisfy) directive inside a [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) container or in your `.htaccess` file to override the authentication requirement.

If your PHP script doesn't need the environment of a full web server, it would be far easier, more secure and would produce less overhead to just execute the script with the PHP command-line interpreter.

Comment: Joschi, thanks for the help and the point in the right direction. Because of the framework of the site, the path to the script isn't really an option. I'd agree with you about the security though. I'll see what I can learn from the links you gave.

Comment: You're a life saver, Joschi. It worked. Thanks a bunch!